# Giving one class' method to another class' friendship

Tags: c++, oop, methods, friend, friend-function

I think title sums it up. I have ***class government*** which has the ***method changeAddress***. This ***changeAddress*** method will take the ***class person*** as a parameter and will change it's ***attribute Address***. But the ***address attribute*** is private, so I wanted to give the ***changeAddress*** function to friendship. I have below code. When I compile it, compiler says;

```
Error   C2653   'government': is not a class or namespace name  27.11.15.02
Error   C2248   'person::address': cannot access private member declared in class 'person'
```

Even though I' ve included header file of government class it doesn't recognize government.

someClass.h file(person class)

```
class person
{

public:
    //friend class government;                                  //this works fine
    friend void government::changeAddress(person*, std::string);//but this couldn't compiled

    std::string name;
    std::string city;
    std::string age;
    int* heapArea;
    uint8_t heapSize;
    static int nbrOfPersons;

    static int getNbrOfPersons();
    std::string getName() const;
    std::string getCity() const;
    std::string getAge() const;
    int* getHeapArea() const;
    int getHeapValue(int index) const;
    void setHeapValue(int index, int val);
    std::string getIdNum() const;
    std::string getAddress() const;

    person(std::string _name = "noName", std::string _city = "noCity",
        std::string _age = "noAge", std::string _idNum = "noId",
        std::string _address = "noAddress", uint8_t _heapSize = 64,
        uint8_t _secretHeapSize = 32);
    person(const person&);
    ~person();

    
private:
    std::string idNum;
    std::string address;
    int* secretHeapArea;
    uint8_t secretHeapSize;

    int* getSecretHeapArea() const;
    int getSecretHeapValue(int)const;
    void setSecretHeapValue(int index, int val);

};
```

government.h file:

```
#pragma once



#include "global.h"         //included <iostream> etc.
#include "someClass.h"      



class government
{
    
public:
    void changeName(person* p, std::string s);
    void changeCity(person* p, std::string s);
    void changeAddress(person*, std::string);
    void deletePerson(person* p);

    government();
    ~government();



private:
};
```

[image]

Comment: change the access type from `private` to `protected` in someClass.h

Comment: [Edit] the question to include your code as text, not an image. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that:

> member functions cannot be declared as friends before the appearance of their complete class declaration.

So to  **solve** this you need to

1. add the include `#include "government.h"` in file **someclass.h** and then
2. remove `#include "someclass.h` from file **government.h** so that it doesn't result in **cyclic dependency**.
3. add a forward declaration `class person;` in file **government.h**

So the modified files looks like:

**someclass.h**

```
#include "government.h"//ADDED THIS INCLUDE
class person
{

public:
    //friend class government;                                  //this works fine
    friend void government::changeAddress(person*, std::string);//but this couldn't compiled

    std::string name;
    std::string city;
    std::string age;
    int* heapArea;
    uint8_t heapSize;
    static int nbrOfPersons;

    static int getNbrOfPersons();
    std::string getName() const;
    std::string getCity() const;
    std::string getAge() const;
    int* getHeapArea() const;
    int getHeapValue(int index) const;
    void setHeapValue(int index, int val);
    std::string getIdNum() const;
    std::string getAddress() const;

    person(std::string _name = "noName", std::string _city = "noCity",
        std::string _age = "noAge", std::string _idNum = "noId",
        std::string _address = "noAddress", uint8_t _heapSize = 64,
        uint8_t _secretHeapSize = 32);
    person(const person&);
    ~person();

    
private:
    std::string idNum;
    std::string address;
    int* secretHeapArea;
    uint8_t secretHeapSize;

    int* getSecretHeapArea() const;
    int getSecretHeapValue(int)const;
    void setSecretHeapValue(int index, int val);

};
```

**government.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "global.h"     
//REMOVED INCLUDE FROM HERE      


class person; //ADDED THIS FORWARD DECLARATION
class government
{
    
public:
    void changeName(person* p, std::string s);
    void changeCity(person* p, std::string s);
    void changeAddress(person*, std::string);
    void deletePerson(person* p);

    government();
    ~government();



private:
};
```

In the above files i have added comments wherever i have made modification.